# Discrepancy in calculating graph coloring code complexity

Tags: python, graph, graph-coloring

Consider the code below. Suppose the graph in question has N nodes with at most D neighbors for each node, and D+1 colors are available for coloring the nodes such that no two nodes connected with an edge have the same color assigned to them. I reckon the complexity of the code below is O(N*D) because for each of the N nodes we loop through the at most D neighbors of that node to populate the set illegal_colors, and then iterate through colors list that comprises D+1 colors. But the complexity given is O(N+M) where M is the number of edges. What am I doing wrong here?

```
def color_graph(graph, colors):
    for node in graph:
        if node in node.neighbors:
            raise Exception('Legal coloring impossible for node with loop: %s' %
                            node.label)

        # Get the node's neighbors' colors, as a set so we
        # can check if a color is illegal in constant time
        illegal_colors = set([
            neighbor.color
            for neighbor in node.neighbors
            if neighbor.color
        ])

        # Assign the first legal color
        for color in colors:
            if color not in illegal_colors:
                node.color = color
                break
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of edges `M`, the maximum degree `D` and the number of nodes `N` satisfy the inequality:
`M <= N * D / 2`.

Therefore `O(N+M)` is included in `O(N*(D+1))`.

In your algorithm, you loop over every neighbour of every node. The exact complexity of that is not `N*D`, but `d1 + d2 + d3 + ... + dN` where `di` is the degree of node `i`. This sum is equal to `2*M`, which is at most `N*D` but might be less.

Therefore the complexity of your algorithm is `O(N+M)`. Hence it is also `O(N*(D+1))`. Note that `O(N*(D+1)) = O(N*D)` under the assumption `D >= 1`.

Saying your algorithm runs in `O(N+M)` is slightly more precise than saying it runs in `O(N*D)`. If most nodes have a lot fewer than `D` neighbours, then `M+N` might be much smaller than `N*D`.

Also note that `O(M+N) = O(M)` under the assumption that every node has at least one neighbour.

Comment: Thank you. Why is the complexity O(M+N)?

Comment: I edited the post to answer. The complexity is `O(N+M)` because `d1 + d2 + d3 + ... + dN = 2*M`, which is at most `N*D` but might be less. Note that `O(N+M) = O(M)` if you exclude graphs where some nodes have no neighbours.

Comment: Suppose K< N vertices don't have neighbors. N-K << N. Then one will iterate K times without doing anything, and for the remaining N-K the number of steps will be d_1 + d_2 +.. +d_{N-K} =2M. So complexity will be O(K + 2M) = O(N+M).  And if K=0, it's O(M). Is this right?

Comment: Yes. If K << N then N-K = O(N) and N = O(N-K) and O(M+N) = O(M). If N-K << N then N = O(K) and O(N+M) = O(K+M).